# Column 'x.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'y.xId'

Tags: java, hibernate

Its my user model

```
public class Users {
    private long id;
    private String userName;
    private String normalizedUserName;
    private String email;
    private String normalizedEmail;
    private boolean emailConfirmed;
    private String passwordHash;
    private String securityStamp;
    private String concurrencyStamp;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private boolean phoneNumberConfirmed;
    private boolean twoFactorEnabled;
    private Date lockoutEnd;
    private boolean lockoutEnabled;
    private int accessFailedCount;
    private long shopId;
    private Date registerDate;

    private Collection<UserTokens> userTokensById;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getNormalizedUserName() {
        return normalizedUserName;
    }

    public void setNormalizedUserName(String normalizedUserName) {
        this.normalizedUserName = normalizedUserName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNormalizedEmail() {
        return normalizedEmail;
    }

    public void setNormalizedEmail(String normalizedEmail) {
        this.normalizedEmail = normalizedEmail;
    }

    public boolean isEmailConfirmed() {
        return emailConfirmed;
    }

    public void setEmailConfirmed(boolean emailConfirmed) {
        this.emailConfirmed = emailConfirmed;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public String getSecurityStamp() {
        return securityStamp;
    }

    public void setSecurityStamp(String securityStamp) {
        this.securityStamp = securityStamp;
    }

    public String getConcurrencyStamp() {
        return concurrencyStamp;
    }

    public void setConcurrencyStamp(String concurrencyStamp) {
        this.concurrencyStamp = concurrencyStamp;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public boolean isPhoneNumberConfirmed() {
        return phoneNumberConfirmed;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumberConfirmed(boolean phoneNumberConfirmed) {
        this.phoneNumberConfirmed = phoneNumberConfirmed;
    }

    public boolean isTwoFactorEnabled() {
        return twoFactorEnabled;
    }

    public void setTwoFactorEnabled(boolean twoFactorEnabled) {
        this.twoFactorEnabled = twoFactorEnabled;
    }

    public Date getLockoutEnd() {
        return lockoutEnd;
    }

    public void setLockoutEnd(Date lockoutEnd) {
        this.lockoutEnd = lockoutEnd;
    }

    public boolean isLockoutEnabled() {
        return lockoutEnabled;
    }

    public void setLockoutEnabled(boolean lockoutEnabled) {
        this.lockoutEnabled = lockoutEnabled;
    }

    public int getAccessFailedCount() {
        return accessFailedCount;
    }

    public void setAccessFailedCount(int accessFailedCount) {
        this.accessFailedCount = accessFailedCount;
    }

    public long getShopId() {
        return shopId;
    }

    public void setShopId(long shopId) {
        this.shopId = shopId;
    }

    public Date getRegisterDate() {
        return registerDate;
    }

    public void setRegisterDate(Date registerDate) {
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Users users = (Users) o;
        return id == users.id &&
                emailConfirmed == users.emailConfirmed &&
                phoneNumberConfirmed == users.phoneNumberConfirmed &&
                twoFactorEnabled == users.twoFactorEnabled &&
                lockoutEnabled == users.lockoutEnabled &&
                accessFailedCount == users.accessFailedCount &&
                shopId == users.shopId &&
                Objects.equals(userName, users.userName) &&
                Objects.equals(normalizedUserName, users.normalizedUserName) &&
                Objects.equals(email, users.email) &&
                Objects.equals(normalizedEmail, users.normalizedEmail) &&
                Objects.equals(passwordHash, users.passwordHash) &&
                Objects.equals(securityStamp, users.securityStamp) &&
                Objects.equals(concurrencyStamp, users.concurrencyStamp) &&
                Objects.equals(phoneNumber, users.phoneNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(lockoutEnd, users.lockoutEnd) &&
                Objects.equals(registerDate, users.registerDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, userName, normalizedUserName, email, normalizedEmail, emailConfirmed, passwordHash, securityStamp, concurrencyStamp, phoneNumber, phoneNumberConfirmed, twoFactorEnabled, lockoutEnd, lockoutEnabled, accessFailedCount, shopId, registerDate);
    }



    public Collection<UserTokens> getUserTokensById() {
        return userTokensById;
    }

    public void setUserTokensById(Collection<UserTokens> userTokensById) {
        this.userTokensById = userTokensById;
    }
}
```

My userToken model have more than one pk so i have 2 class
its my UserTokens model

```
public class UserTokens implements Serializable {
    private long userId;
    private String loginProvider;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private Date registerDate;
    private Users usersByUserId;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getRegisterDate() {
        return registerDate;
    }

    public void setRegisterDate(Date registerDate) {
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserTokens that = (UserTokens) o;
        return userId == that.userId &&
                Objects.equals(loginProvider, that.loginProvider) &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                Objects.equals(value, that.value) &&
                Objects.equals(registerDate, that.registerDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, loginProvider, name, value, registerDate);
    }

    public Users getUsersByUserId() {
        return usersByUserId;
    }

    public void setUsersByUserId(Users usersByUserId) {
        this.usersByUserId = usersByUserId;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UserTokensPK implements Serializable {
    private long userId;
    private String loginProvider;
    private String name;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getLoginProvider() {
        return loginProvider;
    }

    public void setLoginProvider(String loginProvider) {
        this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserTokensPK that = (UserTokensPK) o;
        return userId == that.userId &&
                Objects.equals(loginProvider, that.loginProvider) &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, loginProvider, name);
    }
}
```

Its my hbm user file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="oauth.identity.Model.Users" table="Users">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="Id" sql-type="bigint"/>
        </id>
        <property name="userName">
            <column name="UserName" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="normalizedUserName">
            <column name="NormalizedUserName" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email">
            <column name="Email" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="normalizedEmail">
            <column name="NormalizedEmail" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="emailConfirmed">
            <column name="EmailConfirmed" sql-type="bit"/>
        </property>
        <property name="passwordHash">
            <column name="PasswordHash" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" length="500" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="securityStamp">
            <column name="SecurityStamp" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" length="500" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="concurrencyStamp">
            <column name="ConcurrencyStamp" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" length="500" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phoneNumber">
            <column name="PhoneNumber" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" length="50" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phoneNumberConfirmed">
            <column name="PhoneNumberConfirmed" sql-type="bit"/>
        </property>
        <property name="twoFactorEnabled">
            <column name="TwoFactorEnabled" sql-type="bit"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lockoutEnd">
            <column name="LockoutEnd" sql-type="datetime2" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lockoutEnabled">
            <column name="LockoutEnabled" sql-type="bit"/>
        </property>
        <property name="accessFailedCount">
            <column name="AccessFailedCount" sql-type="int"/>
        </property>
        <property name="shopId">
            <column name="ShopId" sql-type="bigint"/>
        </property>
        <property name="registerDate">
            <column name="RegisterDate" sql-type="datetime2"/>
        </property>
        <set name="userTokensById" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="UserId"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" class="oauth.identity.Model.UserTokens"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and hbm UserToken

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="oauth.identity.Model.UserTokens" table="UserTokens">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="loginProvider">
                <column name="LoginProvider" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256"/>
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="name">
                <column name="Name" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" length="256"/>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="value">
            <column name="Value" sql-type="nvarchar(4000)" length="4000" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="registerDate">
            <column name="RegisterDate" sql-type="datetime2"/>
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="usersByUserId" class="oauth.identity.Model.Users">
            <column name="UserId"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my application context

```
 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://DPK-122\MSSQLSERVER2014;databaseName=SHC1;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER2014;"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Users.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>UserTokens.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

i think all thing is fine but it give me an error and dont work as excepted

```
Column 'Users.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'UserTokens.UserId' in foreign key 'FKe2l2gfho1gf1q3srduiy8owig'.
```

Both id type is big int i cant understand where is my fault ?

Answer (score 0):

In your UserToken mapping file the SQL type is not present in

```
<column name="UserId"/>
```

While you have it in the User mapping

```
<column name="Id" sql-type="bigint"/>
```